# Entity Framework 6 Power Tools not working with Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: frameworks, entity

I am just getting started with Entity Framework and have hit a roadblock. I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and just installed "Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition".. restarted Visual Studio and it shows me context menu of Entity Framework but when I click on View Entity Data Model (Read-only) option on a class derived from DBContext, it is giving me following error:

> "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject'."

Comment: You probably should better visit Microsoft forum and/or knowledge base to be able to get more information about your issue.

Comment: Tried but no information about this anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I added a Project type Class Library (.Net Standard) instead of Class Library (.Net framework), changing this solved the problem